# Inequality of logarithm function in terms of $L^p$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

I am struggling to show that

for $f\in L^q([0,1])$ with $q>0$,

$\int_{[0,1]}\log|f|dm\leq \log\left\| f \right\|_q $.

I even don't know how to start :(  Hope I can get some help :)

Comment: Just apply Jensen.

Comment: @Shalop  That works!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- $\forall p>0, \forall q\in(p,+\infty), \|f\|_p\le\|f\|_q$;
- $\lim_{q\rightarrow 0^+} \|f\|_q=\exp\left(\int_{[0,1]}\log|f(t)|\operatorname{d}t\right)$